# RecycleView - android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Today I decided to use RecycleView as my ListView (as recommended from Android 5.0). I have used [**this tutorial**](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/) to get started as I have never used RecyclerView before.

I have checked all my Java and XML code, there are no errors. I have imported the android-support-v7-recyclerview multiple times, tried Project > Clean multiple times, restarted Eclipse but nothing works. I have appcompat_v7 and android-support-v4 included in the project and never had a problem with either.

Upon starting my application the app crashes and get this in logcat

```
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795): Process: com.stackoverflow.question, PID: 2795
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stackoverflow.question/activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #158: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #158: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     ... 10 more
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     ... 22 more
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method create(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/view/animation/Interpolator;)Landroid/support/v4/widget/ScrollerCompat; in class Landroid/support/v4/widget/ScrollerCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.widget.ScrollerCompat' appears in /data/app/com.stackoverflow.question-1/base.apk)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.<init>(RecyclerView.java:2686)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:231)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:266)
01-21 13:31:45.522: E/AndroidRuntime(2795):     ... 25 more
```

I have been fighting this issue for over 3 hours, searched through many posts with no result. I can prevent the app from crashing by removing `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView .... />` from my activity_main.xml therefore I am sure it's something I am doing wrong with the RecyclerView.

I would apriciate any help as right now I have no idea what to or what to try to get it to work. Could it be the support library?

PS: Package name re-named for this question in logcat

Comment: Make sure that your project has the latest `support-v4` JAR file. It feels like `appcompat-v7` is expecting something that your `support-v4` lacks for some reason.

Comment: @CommonsWare, It did actually work, I replaced every single of the support-v4 and appcompat-v7 to the same ones. I believe BaseGameUtils were using a different version of support-v4. Spent 3 hours playing with the code when it was actually the libs. Lesson learnt. Post your comment as a question so I can mark it as complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency management can be aggravating.

With Android Studio, you would have declared a dependency on `appcompat-v7`, and Gradle for Android would have found a compatible `support-v4` and used it. Much of the time, that's all that is needed.

With Eclipse, though, you have to do that all by hand. If you upgrade a library (e.g., `appcompat-v7`) that depends on another library (e.g., `support-v4`), you need to ensure that you are using a compatible pair, typically by upgrading them both at the same time. This can lead to challenges when you use third-party libraries that themselves depend upon, and perhaps even ship, something like `support-v4`.